# regexp character or end of line with egrep

Tags: grep

I have following regexp:

```
egrep '(chr1 .*n70$|chr1 .*n70-)' results/files/forbidden_variants
```

This matches

```
chr1 n70
chr1 n70-n79
chr1 n70-n79-n83
chr1 n70-n79
chr1 n70-n79-s15-s16
chr1 n70
chr1 n70-n91
chr1 n70
```

and is terribly slow as I am replacing ids such as n70 with different values millions of times.

Therefore I wanted to get rid of OR. I have written:

```
egrep '(chr1 .*n70[-\$])' results/files/forbidden_variants
```

but it is not working as I am not matching end of line with this command. Output looks like this:

```
chr1 n70-n79
chr1 n70-n79-n83
chr1 n70-n79
chr1 n70-n79-s15-s16
chr1 n70-n91
```

What am I doing wrong here? :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a + to the current Regex :

```
egrep '(chr1 n70[-\$]+)' results/files/forbidden_variants
```

Comment: This matches also chr1 n7006

Comment: Have a look at the edit. It doesn't match strings like 'chr1 n7006' any more.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simply

```
chr1 n70
```

you can use a OR

```
chr1 n70($|-)
```

which is basically equivalent to your first expression, but in your first expression i don't see the need of .* in your matches.

Comment: Because n70 can be also in the middle of the expression, like this n79-n70-s15-s16

Comment: you'll need to have (chr1 n70) in the middle of your expression to be match not only n70